# My succulent plant is developing a yellow stem and white silky strands. Is this normal?

Tags: diagnosis, succulents

My succulent plant's stem is starting to get shriveled, and its weak (can't support its own weight) along with yellow. I'm starting to use straws and wooden stakes to support it. Leaves are falling off super fast, and I don't want my succulent (like many others) to die!

Some basic information:

- Waters on average every 2 days (I don't think it is overwatering, I accidentally didn't water for 21-28 days, and now it's like this. Before, it was fine). I water with one of those little cleaning spray bottles with ~5 squirts every time
- Height is about 1 inch (2.54 cm)
- I don't really know about nutrients
- Hours of direct light is approximately 5-6 hours depending on weather
- Lives in a sort-of wet place (inner east coast of US)
- Temperature averages at 71F (21C)
- Using succulent soil

[image: im1]
[image: im2]
[image: im3]

Comment: Good question and good comments; if could include an overall illustration & closer illustrations of the top & leaves & stem, overall height, current watering amount, current nutrient amount & frequency, and  hours of direct light & hours diffuse light it receives per day, could be helpful. And if in a container: size of container, and if some coarse gravel in the bottom and a hole in the bottom for good aereation & drainage, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestions are going to be based on the most common problems for all houseplants:

- too much water too often
- not enough light
- poor drainage

It appears the soil is the standard soil less mix which is peat based and does a great job of retaining water. Your plant is a succulent and would benefit from a soil mix that has better drainage.  A plant like this would be happier being watered once every few weeks if it was getting enough light. Confirm that the pot has a drainage hole at the bottom. When watering add enough water so it comes out the bottom of the pot and remove standing water from the tray after watering.

Consider moving this plant right next to a south facing window which gets unobstructed sun for at least eight hours a day. More is better!

You can use a soil less mix if you add material to promote drainage like:

- grit
- [sharp sand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp_sand)  (not play sand)
- perlite or vermiculite  (both have their issues as perlite is dusty and vermiculite breaks down with time so they are not my first choice)

To resolve the webbing on the plants I recommend getting a Q tip or similar and some isopropyl rubbing alcohol available at the drugstore. Dip the Q tip in the solution and rub it over the plant stems. Repeat if necessary.  I think the webs are a soil mould encouraged by damp conditions that is eating the organic matter in the soil. It is harmless but if I am wrong and it is mealy bug then the isopropyl is a good control.

Comment: If I don't have a south (or north) window, where should I put it?

Comment: there is a drainage hole

Comment: @PythonPikachu8 If you don't have a window with more light then consider an artificial light on for at least 8 hours a day

Comment: @kevisky Any artificial light?

Comment: @PythonPikachu8 You will get better results with a grow light but anything is better than nothing.

Comment: Ok, I will try it!

Comment: i can't switch my soil right now. Also, for the silky stuff, it's kind of like a "branch" of the plant- it's attached to it. More like little strands than a web.